# Using Remote Registry in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have searched in Google and tried several examples from Stackoverflow and other websites. While I can use the commands in the solutions to get registry settings for some things, I cannot get the information from the path below.

HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM\Config

I know this path is valid because I can pull it up in the registry and can pull it up using remote registry outside of Powershell. The command I'm using is below.

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName ABC-V-12345 -Credential: 'domain\username' {Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM\Config'}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Cannot find path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Interwoven\WorkSite' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Interwoven\WorkSite:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ABC-V-12345
```

How can I get the return data from this command?

Below is a screenshot of the commands and errors messages received from each command.

[image: Various PS Commands and Error Messages]

Comment: `HKCU\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM\Config` you had a colon in it.

Comment: @Mark I made the change and still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

Without using `Invoke-Command`, you can get this info using `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey()` on the `HKEY_USERS` registry hive.
For this, you need to know the (string) user SID which is obtained easily enough using the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet.

The below code assumes you want to get this registry info for the user that is currently logged on the remote computer:

```powershell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$computerName = 'ABC-V-12345'

# get the domain\username of the user currently logged in to the computer
$user = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computerName).UserName
# get the SID for that user 
$sid = (Get-ADUser -Identity $(($user -split '\\', 2)[0])).SID
if (!$sid) {
    Throw "Could not determine the SID for user '$user'"
}

# read the values in registry key 'HKEY_USERS\$sid\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM\Config'
$hive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::Users
$path = "$sid\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM\Config"

try {
    $base = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hive, $computerName)
    $key  = $base.OpenSubKey($path)
    if (!$key) {
        Write-Warning "Registry key '$path' does not exist"
    }
    else {
        $result = foreach ($ValueName in $key.GetValueNames()) {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'ValueName' = if (!$ValueName -or $ValueName -eq '@') { "(Default)" } else { $ValueName }
                'ValueData' = $key.GetValue($ValueName)
                'ValueKind' = $key.GetValueKind($ValueName)
            }
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Throw
}
finally {
    if ($key)  { $key.Close() }
    if ($base) { $base.Close() }
}

# output on screen
$result | Sort-Object ValueName

# or output to CSV file
$result | Sort-Object ValueName | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. If you are not on an ActiveDirectory domain, you can get the SID for the user with below function:

```powershell
function Get-UserSID {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('Account', 'User')]
        [string]$UserName = $env:USERNAME,
        [string]$Domain   = $env:USERDOMAIN
    )
    if ($UserName.Contains("\")) { $Domain, $UserName = $UserName -split '\\', 2 }   #"# split on the backslash
    try {
        $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Domain, $UserName)
        $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $strSID.Value
    }
    catch [System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException] {
        Write-Warning "User '$UserName' does not exist in '$Domain'"
    }
    catch {
        throw
    }
}
```

Use this with:

```powershell
$user = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computerName).UserName
$sid = Get-UserSID $user
```

Comment: The first part of the code generates an error and the second part returns nothing but throws no error.

Comment: @webby68 _an error_ is not very helpful. What error did you get and on which part of the code. Have you googled this error? What did you try? Do you have permission to read remote registry? What version of PowerShell ate you using?

Comment: We don't have access to use the AD module so I cannot get any information because the error states that all the commands aren't recognized after saying the module for ActiveDirectory was not loaded.  The second one state "Get-UserSID : The term 'Get-UserSID' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.". Yes, I've Googled for extensive amount of time, hence the post here, I've tried all suggestions in other StackOverflow resolutions, yes permissions set, 5.0

Comment: @webby68 If they gave you permission to access remote registry, then why are you not allowed to use the ActiveDirectory module?? I think you need to talk to the system administrators in your organization to explain that because of these restrictions it is hardly possible to do your job.

Comment: @webby68 `Get-UserSID` is a self-defined function. This should be pasted in the code **before** you try to call it, otherwise PowerShell won't know it exists. (standard PowerShell behavior)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 cmdlets on this space. So, which aspect of the hives will determine which to use. DO, you get not found for all three?

> [Get-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7) Gets the item at the specified location.

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName 'ABC-V-12345' -ScriptBlock {Get-Item -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM\Config'} -Credential 'domain\username'
```

> [Get-ItemProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty?view=powershell-7) Gets the properties of a specified item.

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName 'ABC-V-12345' -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM -Name Config'} -Credential 'domain\username'
```

[Get-ItemPropertyValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue?view=powershell-7)
Gets the value for one or more properties of a specified item.

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName 'ABC-V-12345' -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM -Name Config'} -Credential 'domain\username'
```

If you just did this...

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName 'ABC-V-12345' -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM' -Recurse} -Credential 'domain\username'
```

... do you also get back not found or nothing?

***Update as per your request moving my comment to here***

> @postnote This worked. Please edit the answer to show this and I will
>   accept it. However, when I got to 8.0 the EMM name wasn't there. I put
>   it in the path manually and it came back with the cannot find the path
>   error. I tried another computer the same way that I knew all the keys
>   were on and I found it. This worked while in the interactive session.
>   Thank you. "Get-ChildItem -Path
>   'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0'"

In the interactive session, don't use the invoke, just use the GCI as normal to see what comes back. So, GCI to only interwoven, then WorkSite, etc... Anytime you see this ...Name[0]... it means you did not pass in all the params needed. Yet, based on what you are doing, that should not be a thing. So, do a GCI one path at a time and see what comes back.

No worries, and glad this got you your result. Yet, anything in an interactive session should work in an implicit remote session / using Invoke. So, as you found out, some systems may not have this, so, change your code to have an if/then or try/catch to deal with that.

Something along the lines of this...

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName 'ABC-V-12345' -ScriptBlock {
Try { Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0' -Recurse}
Catch {Write-Warning -Message "The registry path / key / value was not found on $env:ComputerName"}
} -Credential 'domain\username'
```

Comment: I get the same exact error message for each one of those you have provided.

Comment: @postnote, I tried each of these commands and got the same error message for all  but the 3rd one. The 3rd one wanted me to enter "Name[0]" and I wasn't sure what to put in there. If you notice, below the 3rd command, I was able to change directory to that path. It found it so I don't understand why the error message says the path doesn't exist.

Comment: That third command is on your local machine vs a remote one. So, if you do a full interactive PSRemote session to a target host and do that manually and see what happens. Also, try stepping back a  directory down or so and see what comes back.

Comment: @postnote I use the command enter-psssession computername then I ran the command. The following is the result. I just don't know what to enter for Name[0]: [ABC-V-12345]: PS C:\Windows\System32> Invoke-Command –ComputerName 'ABC-V-12345' -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0\EMM -Name Config'} -Credential 'domain\username'
cmdlet Get-ItemPropertyValue at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]:

Comment: In the interactive session, don't use the invoke, just use the GCI as normal to see what comes back. So, GCI to only interwoven, then WorkSite, etc... Anytime you see this ...Name[0]... it means you did not pass in all the params needed. Yet, based on what you are doing, that should not be a thing. So, do a GCI one path at a time and see what comes back.

Comment: @postnote This worked. Please edit the answer to show this and I will accept it. However, when I got to 8.0 the EMM name wasn't there. I put it in the path manually and it came back with the cannot find the path error. I tried another computer the same way that I knew all the keys were on and I found it. This worked while in the interactive session. Thank you. "Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Interwoven\WorkSite\8.0'"